# LiClipse theme: Theme does not apply to strings

Tags: string, themes, pydev, liclipse

I use a particular color theme in the appearance preferences of LiClipse to change the appearance of the text in my editor for my PyDev projects.
I can easily change the color of any type of data that the editor interprets, except for strings. (Perhaps there's more but I have yet to discover them)

I am able in the Preference setting window to set any colors for strings, and I do see it being applied in the preview that the window shows, but when I click Apply, the strings in my code stays plain white. I've tried editing a couple of other data's color, and they all work great.

Following is two screenshots showing the settings window just before pressing "Apply", and my resulting code, in that order.
In the Preferences window, we can see in the preview that the `"String"` part is colored. Any color works. But then in my editor we can see that it did not apply, but all the other word object colors did.

[image: Screenshot of preferences window]

[image: Code example that shows some colors]

My guess is that perhaps the strings in the PyDev editor are not interpreted as `string`, but instead something else.

I'm using LiClipse 4.5.2.201803171104

On Windows 7.

Comment: avoid adding images of your code , add the code into your question as text

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Well, my question is all about the color of the code, not the code itself. Without the screenshot, it would break the whole purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of trial and errors, I found out that by default, strings in the LiClipse PyDev editor are interpreted as `constant`.

Therefore, editing the color of `constant` changes the display colors of strings in the editor.